# How to fix a not creating file

Tags: lua

I want to create a file using lua. But an error occurs.

I using luajit-2.0.5.

`local f = io.open("C://Users//lolgo//OneDrive//Рабочий стол//lua//test.txt", "a")
f:write('Hello world\n')
f:close()`

I expected the code to work, but it gives an error.`attempt to index local 'f' (a nil value)`

Comment: I think the issue is not the slashes but the use of UTF encoding in filenames. See http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-08/msg00150.html and http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2019-01/msg00077.html

Comment: Filename must be encoded in Windows-1251.  In other words, your Lua script must be saved in "ANSI" encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 6.8: Input Output Facilities: io.open](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.open)

> **io.open (filename [, mode])**
>
> This function opens a file, in the mode
> specified in the string mode. In case of success, it returns a new
> file handle.

You cannot just expect this operation to work. So you have to check if io.open actually returned a file handle befor you attempt to index it.

You need some sort of error handling.

```
local f = io.open("C://Users//lolgo//OneDrive//Рабочий стол//lua//test.txt", "a")
if f then
  f:write('Hello world\n')
  f:close()
else
  print("cannot access file")
end
```

Either there is a problem with your path or with user rights.

In your case it is most likely because of the double slashes in the path.

Use double backslash to get a single backslash or use a single slash.

Answer (score 0):

It fails to open the file because the path is wrong. There's no reason to have touble slashes in there; just change it to `"C:/Users/lolgo/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/lua/test.txt"` and it should work.

Since `op.open` doesn't throw an error, but instead returns `nil` + error message, it doesn't crash there, but in the next line where you attempt to index `f`, which is `nil`.

If you want to handle those cases, check whether `f` is nil after attempting to open the file and, if it is, do something else.

```lua
local f, err = io.open(...)
if not f then
  print("Error opening file!")
  -- Try something else instead
else
  f:write("Hello World!\n")
  f:close()
end
```

If it's OK for the program to crash when the file can't be opened, turn the call to `io.open(...)` into `assert(io.open(...))` and it will automatically crash when `io.open` returns `nil` and make use of the provided error message, so you can more easily find possible future problems.

```lua
local f = assert(io.open(...))
f:write('Hello world\n')
f:close()
```